# Catching the last returned value in Unix

Tags: shell-script

please help me with this.

I am doing a grep test file.txt and I want to catch the whole value and print it.I am doing this,

```
grep test file.txt
if [ "$?" -eq 0]
then
echo success
else
echo fail
fi
```

In this code, whether the grep returns a value or not always the exit code is 0 as the command is successful.

I do not want to do the following as my actual code has repetitive greps, say 10 times and it is not working.

```
a=`grep test file.txt`
if [ "$a" -eq "" ]
then
echo fail
else
echo success
fi
```

I am looking for a simple solution like this,

echo $(anything) should catch the value.

Answer (score 4):

Your results don't match mine

```
echo 'some test here' > file.txt
grep test file.txt
echo $?    # returns 0

echo 'something else here' > file.txt
grep test file.txt
echo $?    # returns 1
```

Furthermore, when I run your own complete code example, I get the "success" or "fail" according to whether or not the keyword exists in the file. (I've added the missing space between the `0` and `]` because otherwise you would be getting the error, `` -bash: [: missing `]' `` and you didn't report that.)

```
grep test file.txt
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
```

However, as a style suggestion I would test the `grep` command directly, like this

```
if grep test file.txt
then
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
```

It's just struck me that you might want to be using the return value from the `grep` after your `if`...`fi` block. In that case just save the value and continue on:

```
grep test file.txt
ss=$?
if [ 0 -eq $ss ]
then
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
# Here $ss still contains the return value from grep
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code should work as expected if you add a `space` between the `0` and the `]`.

```
grep test file.txt
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
echo success
else
echo fail
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep test file.txt
if [ "$?" -eq 0]
then
  echo success
  exitcode=0
else
  echo fail
  exitcode=1 
fi
exit ${exitcode}
```

I am not sure what you are looking for but if you want your script to exit with the same code as your `grep` command did, this should work for you.

If you are looking for something else, you should try to explain yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

Could pipe through awk instead of relying on the return code.

```
grep posix test_file.txt|awk 'BEGIN{matches=0}{matches++}END{if(matches>0){print "success";}else{print "fail";}}'
```

Print only the first match:

```
grep testvalue test_file.txt|awk 'BEGIN{matches="";}{matches=$0;}END{if(matches!=""){print "success";print matches;}else{print "fail";}}'
```

And with the value catching feature where every grep match is shown:

```
grep testvalue test_file.txt|awk 'BEGIN{matches="";}{matches=matches $0 "\n";}END{if(matches!=""){print "success";print matches;}else{print "fail";}}'
```